# UINavigationControllerのtitleを空にしtitleViewを使うと空間が出来る

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uikit, uinavigationcontroller

UINavigationControllerの戻るボタンの文字をtitle=""で空にして、合わせてnavigationItem.titleView=UISearchBar()のように検索バーをセットするとtitleViewと戻るの間に空間が出来る問題を解決したいと考えています。どなたか良い解決方法をご存知ありませんでしょうか。

[image: 症状のスクリーンショット]

Answer (score 1):

解決になるかどうかはわかりませんが、戻るボタンを自作する事で、隙間を減らす事は出来ます。
（Xcode 7.2.1／iOS9.2のシミュレーター環境で確認）

[image: 戻るボタンの比較画像]

ソースコードはこんな感じになります。

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // サーチバーを追加
        let sb = UISearchBar()
        navigationItem.titleView = sb

        // 標準とそっくりの画像でUIBarButtonItemを作成
        let img = UIImage(named: "back-image")
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: img, style: .Plain, target: self, action: "backMenu")
    }

    /// 前の画面に戻る
    func backMenu() {
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```